# How do we share folder on windows host to windows based docker container?

Tags: docker

My requirement is to mount an nfs drive to windows based docker container.

I tried below command:

```
docker run -v "$HOME\foo:C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\foo" --mount type=volume,dst=M:\,volume-opt=type=nfs,volume-opt=device=:FileSystem-D,volume-opt=o=addr=192.168.0.10 -p 80:80 -p 81:81 -p 443:443 -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 -p 4848:4848 -it --entrypoint="docker-entrypoint.bat" docker/win2019 cmd
```

producing following error:

```
"docker: Error response from daemon: create 47becc3936dec62c463726b91fa4206324326fa36d148aabaec1aceca2a8dd6e: options are not supported on this platform."
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to,

1. Mount the NFS to the host.
2. Use Docker to mount the file path of the NFS share, that is mounted onto your host machine, so you are using the host pc to connect to the network share and not directly from the container.

Comment: -v parameter is not supported in windows environments. I am getting "options are not supported on this platform"